# is there a way to make a public static class in java?

Tags: java, class, static

So I am following [this tutorial](https://cadiboo.github.io/tutorials/1.14.4/forge/1.7-itemgroup/)
and I have run into a problem, the code provided does not work with all the information I got/understood.

```
public static class ModItemGroup extends ItemGroup {

    private final Supplier<ItemStack> iconSupplier;

    public ModItemGroup(final String name, final Supplier<ItemStack> iconSupplier) {
        super(name);
        this.iconSupplier = iconSupplier;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemStack createIcon() {
        return iconSupplier.get();
    }

    public static final ItemGroup MOD_ITEM_GROUP = new ModItemGroup(Main.MODID, () -> new ItemStack(Items.LIGHT_BLUE_BANNER));


}
```

The problem is on the first line (according to IntelliJ), "Modifier 'static' not allowed here". But if I remove the 'static' it does still not work. I would like to know how I can either fix this / work around this.
I have read about static nested classes but I didn't get it to work with the other code in this post.
It is probably something simple again that I have just missed, and I am sorry if that's the case.

Comment: Why do you want to write a `public static class`? What do you think should be the semantics? You can write an inner `public static class`, but the `static` has a somewhat different semantics than it has on variables/methods.

Comment: "still doesnt work" isnt a problem description we could help with. The code looks good, maybe ModItemGroup ... isnt in a file named ModItemGroup.java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` as a class modifier causes an inner class to be treated as a separate entity, as opposed to requiring a reference to an instance of the enclosing class. It thus only ever makes sense to have it on an inner class, so **it's only allowed on inner classes, not top level classes.** The tutorial says the following:

> Then make a new class called “ModItemGroups” in that package. Next, create an public static inner class called “ModItemGroup” that extends ItemGroup (from net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup) **in ModItemGroups**

It's not very clear (I can't exactly say I rate this tutorial after a quick look, though that's another matter entirely), but this will need to be defined *within the ModItemGroups* class, not as a top level class.

Answer (score 1):

This should be an Inner class, you can check this tutorial to understand more about inner classes : https://www.javatpoint.com/static-nested-class

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have class marked as static. The only exception is the nested class, which can be marked as static. This static inner class can access the static variable of outer class including those marked private. It cannot access non-static variables of the outer class.